# cannot make redirect to anather page in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, function, if-statement, redirect

I'm try to make  redirect page with slug if have activity to page activity and if news redirect to news page. but when i make if else in foreach cannot.

this my controller

```
    $term = request('search');

    $results = Search::add(activity::class, 'title','activity', 'district')
    ->add(news::class, 'title','body')
    ->beginWithWildcard()
    ->get($term);

    return view('/search',[
        **'search' => $results,**
        'term'    => $term,
    ]);

}
```

this is may view :

```
 <div class="ride_section_2 layout_padding mt-5">
    @foreach ($search as $item)
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="image_3"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/700x300?nature,water" class="card-img-top mb-3" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <h1 class="cabe_text">{{ $item->title }}</h1>
          <p class="long_text">{{ $item->excerpt }} <br>            
              **@if ($item->count() > 0 )
                <a href="/posts/{{ $item->slug }}">read more...</a> </p>
              @else
                 <a href="/news/{{ $item->slug }}">read more...</a> </p>
              @endif**

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    @endforeach
 </div>
```

Comment: what is the error? we need to know errors.

Comment: First of all, you should use the `route()` helper to create links instead of concatenating the links yourself.

Comment: In your controller you're calling the view with `view('/search')`, `view()` asks for a blade, and you're giving him a route. So either correct with `route()` (and be sure to have the correct function in the controller) or replace inside `view()` with a call to your blade.

Comment: this not a error, but i want to if my data show post link /post/slug actif when data show news link /news/slug is actif so i confuse with my if condision not work like i want

Answer (score 0):

You're using https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-cross-eloquent-search right?

And you want to link to the /news/{slug} or /posts/{slug} depending on the type of result (activity/news).

You should check for the Model type and then assign the appropriate route to it, eg.

```
@foreach ($search as $item)
    @if($item instanceof \App\Models\news)
        <a href="{{ route('news.show', $item) }}">{{ $item->title }}</a>
    @else
        <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $item) }}">{{ $item->title }}</a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```